# Is there a way to do concurrent editing in Magento?

Tags: magento, concurrency, editing

Is there a MediaWiki-like method for supporting concurrent editing of text bodies/ or even product data in Magento? (in the admin)

If i want to implement this function, what should be the concerns?

Can anyone suggest some approach & situation that i should consider?

I have considered few function:

1. when admin user enter product edit page, he must click the "start edit" button
2. after clicked, the screen will show the concurrent user in this page(who also click "start edit")
3. if one of them has submitted the saving, the other one cannot save it and an error will be displayed as " The content on this page has either been modified by another user, or you have already submitted modifications using this form. As a result, your changes cannot be saved."  It will validate in every content saving.

Comment: currently magento doesn't support such feature

Comment: i think so, actually it is a cms function. However i want to explore more on the possibility of it

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't support this feature, but it is not hard to implement this with a little customization.
Firstly you need add lock entity in Magento, better to add a sperated lock resource model(which it at least has asset type, asset id, lockUserId, lockStartTime..etc ). Thus every time if merchandiser want to change something , it will insert one lock record into this resouce model if there's no exist lock record.
You can find the corresponding event in Magento and add one new observer event appended to that. So the lock merchanism can be done following this way.